I want to create the Lead form using LWC
I need to create a public lead form using LWC. When a seller fills out the form and submits it, the details should be saved as a record in my Lead object. I have designed the form using HTML, imported all the fields from the Lead object in my JavaScript, and implemented the logic in my JavaScript. I have also created an Apex class. My question is whether creating a community site or a normal site page is sufficient. Could you please suggest which option to choose? because when i submit the form i am getting the error even i have provided all the permission at guest user profile .
